# jQuery - Как найти предыдущий элемент?

Tags: jquery

Структура следующая

```
<div id="1" data-level="0">Комментарий</div>
  <div id="3" style="padding-left:20px" data-level="1">Ответ</div>
    <div id="4" style="padding-left:40px" data-level="2">Ответ на ответ</div>
    <div id="5" style="padding-left:40px" data-level="2">Ответ на ответ</div>
      <div id="7" style="padding-left:60px" data-level="3">Ответ на ответ на ответ</div>
      <div id="8" style="padding-left:60px" data-level="3">Ответ на ответ на ответ</div>
    <div id="6" style="padding-left:40px" data-level="2">Ответ на ответ</div>
<div id="2" data-level="0">Комментарий</div>
```

Как в этой структуре найти допустим, что у элемента id='8' родительский элемент это div с id='5'.

Попытки решить задачу:

```
$('div[data-level]').each(function(){
  var t = $(this),
      level = t.attr('data-level'),
      parent = $('div[data-level="'+(level-1)+'"]').attr('id');
      //parent = $('div[data-level="'+(level-1)+'"]').prev().attr('id');
      //parent = $(this).('div[data-level="'+(level-1)+'"]').prev().attr('id');
      //parent =  t.prev('div').attr('id');

  if ( level > '0' ) {
    t.attr( "data-parent", parent );
    t.html( 'Рельный ID:'+ t.attr('id') + ' Родительский:'+ parent );
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdwYYP

Comment: `Как в этой структуре найти допустим, что у элемента id='8' родительский элемент это div с id='5'.` – оне не является родительским в вашем примере

Comment: это первый предыдущий  с дата-левел на один меньше, видимо, так

Comment: по коду да, но по факту так и есть

Comment: ^ пять баллов :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', "div", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $dest = $this.prevAll("[data-level='" + ($this.data('level')-1) + "']").first();
  
  if ($dest.length) {
    $dest.css('background', "red");
    setTimeout(function() { $dest.css('background', ""); }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  transition: all 3s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="1" data-level="0">Комментарий</div>
  <div id="3" style="padding-left:20px" data-level="1">Ответ</div>
    <div id="4" style="padding-left:40px" data-level="2">Ответ на ответ</div>
    <div id="5" style="padding-left:40px" data-level="2">Ответ на ответ</div>
      <div id="7" style="padding-left:60px" data-level="3">Ответ на ответ на ответ</div>
      <div id="8" style="padding-left:60px" data-level="3">Ответ на ответ на ответ</div>
    <div id="6" style="padding-left:40px" data-level="2">Ответ на ответ</div>
<div id="2" data-level="0">Комментарий</div>
```

Comment: так , пожоже, он не родитель в смысле структуры html

Comment: @splash58, да, понял. Сейчас поправлю. Меня форматирование разметки сбило.

Comment: @ВикторОнходоев, поправил.

Comment: @splash58, поправил.

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее!)

Comment: Хм.. @ВикторОнходоев, я тут полдумал, что не уверен в порядке элементов от prevAll, но вроде работает.